# Tikzcd and classicthesis

Tags: classicthesis, tikz-cd

I want to use commuting diagrams and the `classicthesis` package.

I've edited the `classicthesis` document so that `tikz`, `tikzcd` and the `braids` packages are included after the `classicthesis` package.

However I get the error:

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/"f"' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

Here's a minimal example:

```
\documentclass[
    oneside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,
    %footinclude=true,
    cleardoublepage=empty,
    dottedtoc, % Make page numbers in the table of contents flushed right with dots leading to them
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
    ngerman,american, % Languages, change this to your language(s)
    ]{scrreprt} 

% Includes the file which contains all the document configurations and packages - make sure to edit this file
\input{classicthesis-config}

 \begin{document}   
 \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
                U
                \arrow[r,hook, "f"]
              & V
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

However: If I write

```
\documentclass[
    oneside,openright,titlepage,numbers=noenddot,headinclude,%1headlines,
    %footinclude=true,
    cleardoublepage=empty,
    dottedtoc, % Make page numbers in the table of contents flushed right with dots leading to them
    BCOR=5mm,paper=a4,fontsize=11pt, % Binding correction, paper type and font size
    ngerman,american, % Languages, change this to your language(s)
    ]{scrreprt} 

% Includes the file which contains all the document configurations and packages - make sure to edit this file
\input{classicthesis-config}

 \begin{document}   
 \begin{center}
    \begin{tikzcd}
                U
                \arrow{r}{f}
              & V
\end{tikzcd}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

everything works fine.
This makes me rather confused. What is it, I'm missing?

Here's a stripped-down version of my classicthesis-config:

```
\PassOptionsToPackage{utf8}{inputenc} 
\usepackage{inputenc}

\PassOptionsToPackage{eulerchapternumbers,listings,drafting, pdfspacing, subfig,beramono,eulermath,parts}{classicthesis}

\newcounter{dummy} 
\providecommand{\mLyX}{L\kern-.1667em\lower.25em\hbox{Y}\kern-.125emX\@}
\newlength{\abcd}   

\PassOptionsToPackage{fleqn}{amsmath} 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\PassOptionsToPackage{T1}{fontenc} 
\usepackage{fontenc}

\usepackage{textcomp} 
\usepackage{scrhack} 
\usepackage{xspace} 
\usepackage{mparhack} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 

%\PassOptionsToPackage{pdftex}{graphicx}
%\usepackage{graphicx} 

\usepackage{tabularx} 
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{3pt} 
\newcommand{\tableheadline}[1]{\multicolumn{1}{c}{\spacedlowsmallcaps{#1}}}
\newcommand{\myfloatalign}{\centering} % To be used with each float for alignment
\usepackage{caption}
\captionsetup{font=small}
\usepackage{subfig}  

\usepackage{classicthesis} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{braids}
\usetikzlibrary{cd}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome. We don't have your `classicthesis-config` of course, so it would be better if you could extract the necessary parts from it and add that to your examples instead of the `\input` line. I wouldn't think `classicthesis` is at all relevant here though, your first example runs fine here if I replace the `\input` with `\usepackage{tikz-cd}`. My guess is that you have an old version of `tikz-cd`. The `"text"` syntax is something that was introduced after version 3.0 of TikZ (which was late 2013 I think), so if your `tikz-cd` is older, then it wouldn't work.

Comment: Sorry for nagging about this, but do you need all of that to demonstrate the problem? Isn't `\usepackage{tikz} \usetikzlibrary{cd}` enough? That said, to check the package version, can you compile the following minimal document, and then post the `.log` file? `\listfiles
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\begin{document}   
a
\end{document}`

Comment: @TorbjørnT.
Since I don't know where the error comes from it isn't enough to just use `usepackage{tikz}` and `usetikzlibrary{cd}`. I have Latex documents with tikz and tikcd that just work fine. It is this very combination that causes the problems.

I run the newest Tikz-cd version 0.9e

Comment: Fair enough, but I still find it hard to believe that all those packages and definitions are actually necessary to reproduce the error. It's a TikZ error. You could try adding `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`, but that library should be loaded by `tikz-cd`. So if that didn't help: Do you by any chance happen to have a file called `tikzlibrarycd.code.tex` in the same folder as the `.tex` file? Can you post the complete  `.log` file of a compilation that resulted in the error?

Comment: Try the newest classicthesis too, v4.4. I just did, and your examples worked... as they did with versions 4.2 and 4.1. I have texlive-tikz-cd-6:svn35485.0.9e-33.fc26, texlive-braids-svn23790.1.0-33.fc26 here.

Comment: The log-file I get is horrendously big. I'll  keep trying to get an easier to read log file.
I've tried  `\usetikzlibrary{qoutes}`which wasn't successful.

Comment: @SeHa The best way to find what's causing the error is to start removing unnecessary packages and package options. Since it worked on my system, I suspect there's a clash in latex packages on yours. Try compiling on some other machine, if possible. And do try the new classicthesis, v4.4.

Comment: So I found a solution to my problem. It was pointed out to me to try to load the tikzlibrary `babel`. This solved my issue. 

However if someone could elaborate where exactly this problem lied and how this solution works I'd be more then happy.

Comment: Seeing as your code works perfectly fine here, it kind of hard to say exactly what caused the problem ... Anyways, I'm guessing that somewhere in your code the `babel` package is loaded (perhaps older versions of `classicthesis` did that). I can reproduce the problem if I replace `\input{classicthesis-config}` with `\usepackage{babel,tikz-cd}`, and adding `\usetikzlibrary{babel}` solved it. Basically read the description of that library in the TikZ manual (page 518, in the manual for TikZ 3.0.1a).

Comment: I agree with you.